# Debugging launcher application

Tags: android, launcher, launching-application

I am trying to create an application that must run in 'kiosk mode', and autolaunch when the device boots.

Right now, if I manually launch AFTER powering up my device, the application launches fine.

However, if I try and define it as a launcher with the following intent filter in my manifest

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
```

it crashes when the device boots.

I don't seem to be getting any useful log info since the application crashes on startup.

Is the issue most likeley initialization related, getting nulls in my onResumer handler? 
If so, how can I confirm and fix?

This is the contents of my onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);

        next_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition_next_in);
        next_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition_next_out);
        previous_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition_previous_in);
        previous_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition_previous_out);

        minutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_minutes);
        minutes.setMaxValue(60);
        seconds = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker_seconds);
        seconds.setMaxValue(60);

        chk_phone = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_phone);
        chk_phone.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkboxListener);
        chk_sms = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_sms);
        chk_sms.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkboxListener);
        chk_weather = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_weather);
        chk_weather.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkboxListener);

        // 1. Get a reference to the UsbManager (there's only one, so you don't
        // instantiate it)
        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);

        // 2. Create the Connection object
        connection = new UsbConnection12(this, mUsbManager);

        // 3. Instantiate the WroxAccessory
        mAccessory = new WroxAccessory(this);
        //*/
}
```

Comment: If its a home replacement screen, can't you install it along side the default launcher, hit the device's 'Home' button and select your own app (without having to reboot)?

Comment: the application must run in kiosk mode, and autolaunch when the device boots

Comment: I've changed my logic to use a bootReceiver instead of just a new home screen as per http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup however now the issue is long delay(3-4 seconds) for boot of my application.

Comment: 3-4 seconds doesn't sound that bad.

Comment: reverted to my original solution using a home screen, no delay now,

Comment: If you fixed it (ie., answered your own question) it would help future visitors if you added an answer and accepted it.  Plus it gives you rep.